# How to select elements stored in a string variable?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

if I have a valid html fragment in a variable like so;

```
var responseText = 'Lorem <span>Ipsum</span>';
```

How can I find the `$("span").html()` of that `responseText`, in other words get the Ipsum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, if `responseText` represented an HTML element, you could have used [`$(responseText)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) to parse it. Here, it easiest to create a temporary element, and setting its [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2):

```
var dummy = $('<div />').html(responseText);
var text = dummy.find('span').text();
```

Working example: http://jsbin.com/ebeju4

Answer (score 1):

```
$('<div/>').html(responseText).find('span').html();
```